# sum acorss sheets in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Sheets , sheet1 called BW, and sheet 2 called reasons.

In sheet 1 I have columns AD till AW, which has to be added individually. i have table in sheet2, where I have listed the column names of AD till AW . in the second column of sheet 2 i Need the sum of column AD till AW. I tried a code like below

```
Sub sum()

    Dim BWlRow As Long, CWlRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Sformula As String
    Dim wsBW As Worksheet, wsCW As Worksheet

    Set wsBW = Sheets("BW"): Set wsCW = Sheets("Reasons")

    BWlRow = wsBW.Cells(wsBW.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    CWlRow = wsCW.Cells(wsCW.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 30 To 47 '
        Sformula = "=SUM(AD2, BW)"


      With wsBW
    With .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(BWlRow, i))
        .Formula = Sformula
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am not able to succeed with this.

[image: I have like this in sheet 1 from column AD till AW]
[image: I Need to have this result.]

Comment: can you explain a little clearer are the images what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Nathan Sav, The Image1 Shows the sheet1 i have and Image 2 Shows the sheet2, in the column result, i want the sum of each column from sheet1.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav should i edit my post still ?

Comment: @Nathan_Savinstead typing in each row in sheet2 in column result =Sum(BW! AD2:AD591) I Need an vba that would sum each column in sheet1 and print the sum result in sheet2 column Result.

Comment: Wouldn't the use of pivot tables be easier?

Comment: Nitesh Halai, The Problem of Pivot is not possible, because i have designed this template in my worksheet. Pivot is not accepting them

Comment: look at `OFFSET` and `MATCH`  offset A1:A100 based on the match of Reason in row 1 of sheet1, a formula would be something like this `=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,0,MATCH(Reason!A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1,0)-1))`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav sorry, i dint get your point

Comment: Give it more than 2 minutes research :)

Comment: I am sorry, i dint understand what you meant, thats why replied quickly.

Comment: you could even have static fomula and derive the headers for reasons from row 1 of sheet 1, so naturally in sync Reason a1=Sheet1 a1, Reason a2=sheet1 b1 for example...

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the above you suggested a formula ? but i Need an VBA

Comment: Which is why I showed the formula, so you can work it out in VBA.  Your code adds a formula any way :)

Comment: instaed doing Offset, i would rather go with sum which will be easy ryt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. `Sheets("BW")` is the sheet why you have data from `Column AD-AW`
2. In `Sheets("Reasons")` `Column A` you have listed down the headers of `Sheets("BW")` `Column AD-AW` in same order, so there's no need to match for the headers
3. You want sum of corresponding `Sheets("Reasons")` `Column A` items in `Sheets("Reasons")` `Column B`
4. Last row of each sheet is on the basis of number of records in `Column A` of both sheets

   ```
   Sub sum()
       Dim BWlRow As Long, CWlRow As Long, i As Long
       Dim Sformula As String
       Dim wsBW As Worksheet, wsCW As Worksheet

       Set wsBW = Sheets("BW"): Set wsCW = Sheets("Reasons")

       BWlRow = wsBW.Cells(wsBW.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       CWlRow = wsCW.Cells(wsCW.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

       Sformula = "=SUM(INDIRECT(""BW!"" & CELL(""address"",OFFSET(AD$2,0,ROW()-2)) & "":"" & CELL(""address"",OFFSET(AD$10,0,ROW()-2))))"

       With wsCW
           With .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(CWlRow, 2))
               .Formula = Sformula
               .Value = .Value
           End With
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you Mrig :) that is very eay to understand also.